# Anchor #top doesn't go all the way to the top

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

When i add #top or #bottom it goes up and down, but not all the way. It goes to the middle of the page instead of the top or bottom.
The #top anchor is just bellow the body tag.

```
<a name="top"></a>
<a href="#top">TOP</a>
```

Comment: Show us some more, that's not enough to go on because that SHOULD work.

Comment: Yes it works, but doesn't go exactly where it should go. It is misplaced 10-20px. When i add <h4 id="heading">Heading</h4> and try to go to this heading using this method, i goes near the heading, 10-20px, not exactly to the heading.